# Showidx shows indexes at the top of the page

Tags: indexing, books, imakeidx

When I compile the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitea\index{vitae}, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue\index{augue}. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.


Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras\index{cras} id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The indices are shown at the top of the page, instead of at their position in the margin next to where the index was defined. That is weird, and I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem.

[image: image demonstrating the indices appearing at the top of the page]

I'm using TeXLive (2015/Debian) from Linux Mint 18, and it does this in both PDFLaTeX en XeLaTeX. Is there anything I've done wrong and does my document compile the same on your setup? I would love to have this issue resolved, as I don't want to use `\marginpar{\small ...}}` everytime as well as the index, nor renew the `\index` command with the risk of messing that up.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  what version of tex live did you process this with?  (it fails miserably with tex live 2016, imakeidx 2016/05/16 v1.3d.  it would be really helpful to know what changes to look for.)

Comment: Something is trying to use `\ifdefequal`, which is an `etoolbox` command, but that package hasn't been loaded. (Unrelated but the example needs `\usepackage{etoolbox}` to compile without error with TL2017.)

Comment: I'm using `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)` found using `tex --version` on Linux Mint 18. I guess they're a few years behind. `imakeidx` is version 2013/07/11 v1.3a. `showidx` is 2014/09/29 v1.0m (found these version by `cat`-ing the .sty files)

Comment: The `\ifdefequal` problem is a small bug, add `\usepackage{etoolbox}`. But `showidx` has been doing that all the time.

Comment: So what you're saying is, `showidx` isn't supposed to show the index next to the line the index is in? @egreg

Comment: @MicroParsec Yes, that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little birdie told me that `showidx` isn't even supposed to show the index at the same line in the margin. That kinda defeats the whole purpose of `showidx` in my opinion, but hey, I think I can fix it.

My solution is the following:

```
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\oldindex{#1}\marginpar{\small#1}}
```

This seems to work. Indexing is not off, and still printed at the end of the document. And most important of all: I get my indices nice and neat at the side of the text, like I'd always wanted.